# Selecting elements from a foreign table matching foreign key?

Tags: mysql

So I have a table called HOURS and in it is a foreign key EMPLOYEE_employee_Num.

the employee table has employee-num as a primary key and there's employee_firstname and Employee_lastName.

how do i select everything from hours table but instead of it showing EMPLOYEE_employee num it is a concat of employee_firstname employee_lastname AS employee?

i've tried joining and union but i'm just not getting it

Comment: so nice, they named it twice

Answer (score 0):

Join the table as usual, and use MySQL's [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) or [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) functions to concatenate the fields, such as:

```
SELECT h.*, CONCAT_WS(' ', e.employee_firstname, employee_lastname) as employee FROM HOURS h INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON e.employee-num = h.EMPLOYEE_employee_Num
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `concat_ws`(**concat** **w**ith **s**eparator) function to concatenate the two name fields and add a blank as separator:

```
SELECT Hours.*, CONCAT_WS(' ',employee_firstname,employee_lastname) as employee
FROM Hours
LEFT JOIN Employee ON Hours.EMPLOYEE_employee_Num = Employee.Employee_Num;
```

Adjust to match your actual column names as needed.

Using a left join mean *get all rows from the left table, and the matching rows from the right* so if there is any rows in `hours`that don't have matching rows in `employee`you will get them too. If there will always be matching rows you can use an`inner join`instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`SELECT hours.*, CONCAT_WS(' ', employee.firstName, employee.lastName) AS employeeName FROM
hours JOIN employee
ON hours.employeeNum = employee.employeeNum`